# Windows server reboots after 5 failed RDP login attempts

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server

We recently discovered a quirk in one of our RDP servers and I cannot figure out why this is happening.

OS: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter - AWS EC2 instance
Low user population system. Between 3 and 5 users simultaneously logged into this system at any time. Used exclusively for SQL access to an AWS RDP SQL Server instance via SSMS.

**Scenario A:**

User starts their day and logs into the remote server via RDP successfully. They use the system for a while, then minimize the window while they work on something else. After the inactivity period elapses, the remote server forces the user to re-enter their credentials.

(All normal up to this point) ...

The user swears they're entering their password the exact same way the logged into the system at the start of the day, but Windows complains it's a bad password. User attempts their password four (4) more times, and the system immediately reboots.

The only thing in the event logs is this message:

```
The process C:\Windows\system32\winlogon.exe (HOSTNAME) has initiated the restart of computer HOSTNAME on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x500ff
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```

**Scenario B (same user as above):**

User connects to a fresh RDP session where they were not previous logged in. Login is successful. They use the system for a while, then minimize the window as before and the remote session eventually forces the user to re-enter their credentials.

Same as before, the user enters their password but the server complains its incorrect.

This time, however, the user closes the RDP window and re-starts the RDP session entirely. Password was accepted this time.

Question: ***What could possibly be causing the server to reboot?*** I see no other evidence of any failures or errors in the system events to point to any software or OS problems.

Comment: Hi, maybe the GPO "Interactive logon: Machine account lockout threshold" cause this trouble. in this article from [technet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj966264(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  the server will be rebooted after failed login attempts. After testing this I got the same event log message.

Comment: @AzureBaum - thanks for the link to that article. This is a very interesting theory. The article mentions bitlocker. Since this is an AWS EC2 instance, we always use EBS encrypted volumes and I've never really even thought about use of bitlocker - but testing just now, the instance won't even let me launch the bitlocker interface. I'll have to spin up a lab instance to test this theory out though -- its certainly worth a look. Thanks again!